# Best Security Model for winforms .NET and SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, winforms

I am trying to determine the best security model for a winforms .NET application connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2. Only stored procedures are executed from .NET to access SQL Server.

We are using only Authenticated users (no SQL logins). Row level data access is restricted using SUSER_SNAME().

Database roles are not restrictive enough because I only want them to be able to execute the stored procedures from the application. Application roles are out because of the connection pooling issue. Linking security to AD user groups is out because my group does not have control over that and it would be an administrative nightmare to have to coordinate.

I am currently looking into mapping security through certificates linked to user accounts, but I don't seem to be able to use those with Windows Authenticated users, only SQL logins.

Any suggestions for a solution, especially with examples or references, would be appreciated.